# Get byte array of string in .NET and convert back in Javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, character-encoding, byte

I need to work with the bytes of a string in two different types of programming environments.

The first environment is .NET, and I'm getting the bytes of the string like this:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello")
```

This give me the output: 48656C6C6F

Then the next environment is Javascript, and I'm attempting to convert the byte array back to a string format:

```
var str = unescape(encodeURIComponent("Hello"));
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < utf8.length; i++) {
    arr.push(utf8.charCodeAt(i));
}
```

When I output the array I get: 72,101,108,108,111

Anyone know what the deal is? Thanks all.

**EDIT**: I'm outputting the array in a browser like:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on what Babak and norbertVC replied with, I took their insight and came up with an alternate solution that worked perfectly for what I'm trying to do:

Instead of using "Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()", I used "ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes()" which allowed me to get an exact match to the same conversion done in Javascript.

So once I had my byte array, placed that into a string and sent the data to my second application. In javascript, I would get substrings of the original byte array string, and in pieces get the matching ASCII character using String.fromCharCode()

Answer (score 0):

You are converting the chars to utf8 char codes.
Use `String.fromCharCode(charCode)` to get it as string.

Comment: I assume that's supposed to go in the javascript. Like this?

    arr.push(String.fromCharCode(i));

Comment: No, don't replace `charCodeAt(i)` - use the result of `charCodeAt(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your value as a String, you could inject it directly into your Javascript if it's directly on an ASP.NET page.

```
var str = '<%= MyStringPropertyFromTheCodeBehind %>';
```

`72,101,108,108,111` are the ASCII codes for the letters in "Hello"

`48656C6C6F` are the same values but in HEX (0x48 = 72 => "H") since .NET strings are UTF-16 (2-byte characters) where as Javascript uses UTF-8 (single byte characters)

Checkout http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Thanks for that insight. But do you know of how I can get the bytes of a string in .NET so that it's encoded as UTF-8. That way javascript can transform it back?

Comment: Why not inject the string directly instead of encoding and decoding back?

Comment: the javascript isn't tied to an asp.net page. Getting the bytes into an array occurs in a class library. In another application I'm able to retrieve that byte array as a string but need to be able to convert back to its original form.